# ActiveMQ Artemis connection-router config in a cluster

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I need to balance incoming connections on the live nodes in my ActiveMQ Artemis cluster using connection-router.

My cluster is made of 2 masters (masterA and masterB) and 2 slaves (slaveA and slaveB) split in 2 groups (group A and group B), that's a 2 live-backup pair. I'm using static cluster connections (tcp), the slave nodes are replicas of the master ones (ha-policy replication).

All works well before I try to add `connection-router`. HA cluster is okay with my base configuration (i.e. before trying to add `connection-router`).

Before I tried to add the `connection-router` config element, the slave nodes were presents in the static-connectors/connector-ref and there was no `router` parameter in the `acceptor` url.

My client app uses a `ConnectionFactory` URL containing both master nodes (slaves cannot accept connections until their master fails and failover happens so I won't put them here).

I have 3 instances of my client app, each capable of handling a single consumer, so what I expect is to have 1 or 2 consumer on each master, which I'm not able to achieve on every startup. Of course it happens sometimes, but that's just coincidence.

The client app uses the admin/admin username and password (for test purpose).

Here are my `broker.xml` of all my 4 instances (relevant sections only):

**masterA**

```xml
<connectors>
    <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
    <connector name="masterA">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
    <connector name="slaveA">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
    <connector name="masterB">tcp://localhost:61626</connector>
    <connector name="slaveB">tcp://localhost:61627</connector>
</connectors>

  <acceptors>

     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61616?router=router-cluster-connection;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

  </acceptors>

  <cluster-user>myclusteruser</cluster-user>

  <cluster-password>myclusterpsw</cluster-password>

  <cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
      <check-period>25001</check-period>
      <connection-ttl>30001</connection-ttl>
      <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
      <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>2</max-hops>
      <notification-interval>500</notification-interval>
      <notification-attempts>100</notification-attempts>
      <static-connectors>
        <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
<!--            <connector-ref>slaveA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>slaveB</connector-ref>-->
      </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <connection-routers>
    <connection-router name="router-cluster-connection">
      <key-type>USER_NAME</key-type>
      <key-filter>admin</key-filter>
      <local-target-filter>admin</local-target-filter>
      <policy name="LEAST_CONNECTIONS" />
      <pool>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
        <quorum-size>2</quorum-size>
        <local-target-enabled>true</local-target-enabled>
        <cluster-connection>my-cluster</cluster-connection>
      </pool>
    </connection-router>
  </connection-routers>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <master>
          <group-name>grappe-a</group-name>
          <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
          <initial-replication-sync-timeout>3600000</initial-replication-sync-timeout>
          <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
        </master>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

**slaveA**

```xml
<connectors>
    <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
    <connector name="masterA">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
    <connector name="slaveA">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
    <connector name="masterB">tcp://localhost:61626</connector>
    <connector name="slaveB">tcp://localhost:61627</connector>
</connectors>


  <acceptors>

     <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

  </acceptors>

  <cluster-user>myclusteruser</cluster-user>

  <cluster-password>myclusterpsw</cluster-password>

  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>slaveA</connector-ref>
      <check-period>25003</check-period>
      <connection-ttl>30003</connection-ttl>
      <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
      <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>2</max-hops>
      <notification-interval>500</notification-interval>
      <notification-attempts>100</notification-attempts>
      <static-connectors>
        <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
<!--            <connector-ref>slaveA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>slaveB</connector-ref>-->
      </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <slave>
          <group-name>grappe-a</group-name>
          <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
          <initial-replication-sync-timeout>36000000</initial-replication-sync-timeout>
            </slave>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

**masterB**

```xml
<connectors>
    <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
      <connector name="masterA">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
      <connector name="slaveA">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
      <connector name="masterB">tcp://localhost:61626</connector>
      <connector name="slaveB">tcp://localhost:61627</connector>
</connectors>

  <acceptors>
     <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61626?router=router-cluster-connection;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

  </acceptors>

  <cluster-user>myclusteruser</cluster-user>

  <cluster-password>myclusterpsw</cluster-password>

  <cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
      <check-period>25002</check-period>
      <connection-ttl>30002</connection-ttl>
      <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
      <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>2</max-hops>
      <notification-interval>500</notification-interval>
      <notification-attempts>100</notification-attempts>
      <static-connectors>
        <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
<!--            <connector-ref>slaveA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>slaveB</connector-ref>-->
      </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <connection-routers>
    <connection-router name="router-cluster-connection">
      <key-type>USER_NAME</key-type>
      <key-filter>admin|NULL</key-filter>
      <local-target-filter>admin|NULL</local-target-filter>
      <policy name="LEAST_CONNECTIONS" />
      <pool>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
        <quorum-size>2</quorum-size>
        <local-target-enabled>true</local-target-enabled>
        <cluster-connection>my-cluster</cluster-connection>
      </pool>
    </connection-router>
  </connection-routers>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <master>
          <group-name>grappe-b</group-name>
          <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
          <initial-replication-sync-timeout>3600000</initial-replication-sync-timeout>
          <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
        </master>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

**slaveB**

```xml
<connectors>
    <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
    <connector name="masterA">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
    <connector name="slaveA">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
    <connector name="masterB">tcp://localhost:61626</connector>
    <connector name="slaveB">tcp://localhost:61627</connector>
</connectors>


  <acceptors>

     <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61627?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

  </acceptors>

  <cluster-user>myclusteruser</cluster-user>

  <cluster-password>myclusterpsw</cluster-password>

  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>slaveB</connector-ref>
      <check-period>25004</check-period>
      <connection-ttl>30004</connection-ttl>
      <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
      <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>2</max-hops>
      <notification-interval>500</notification-interval>
      <notification-attempts>100</notification-attempts>
      <static-connectors>
        <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
<!--            <connector-ref>slaveA</connector-ref>
        <connector-ref>slaveB</connector-ref>-->
      </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>


  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <slave>
          <group-name>grappe-b</group-name>
          <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
          <initial-replication-sync-timeout>36000000</initial-replication-sync-timeout>
        </slave>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

ActiveMQ Artemis version is 2.22.0, running on java 11.

How am I supposed to configure the connection-router in my brokers to evenly balance incoming connections?

Is it supported and a best practice to have HA on a broker doing connection-routing only?

If I add the connection-router element in the slave brokers, they fail to replicate. Is that expected? In case a master fails and failover happens, how can the connection-router feature still work if I can't add it on slaves if I want them to replicate?

I'll provide more details if needed.

**Update**
The router relevant config elements

```xml
<connectors>
    <connector name="masterA">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
    <connector name="slaveA">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
    <connector name="masterB">tcp://localhost:61626</connector>
    <connector name="slaveB">tcp://localhost:61627</connector>
    <connector name="routerA">tcp://localhost:61620</connector>
</connectors>

<acceptors>
    <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://127.0.0.1:61620?router=router-cluster-connection;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>
</acceptors>

<connection-routers>
    <connection-router name="router-cluster-connection">
        <key-type>USER_NAME</key-type>
        <key-filter>admin</key-filter>
        <policy name="ROUND_ROBIN" />
        <pool>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
            <quorum-size>2</quorum-size>
            <local-target-enabled>false</local-target-enabled>
            <static-connectors>
                <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
                <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
        </pool>
    </connection-router>
</connection-routers>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LEAST_CONNECTIONS` policy is good to evenly balance incoming connections but it has not been tested with HA (the replication issue due to backup brokers with connection routers should be fixed by [ARTEMIS-4113](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4113)).

Often, it is better to partition data across brokers than to balance incoming connections to improve performances, for further details see the [symmetric-simple](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/connection-router/symmetric-simple) example.

To avoid a SPOF you could use a symmetric architecture, see the [symmetric-redirect](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/connection-router/symmetric-redirect) and the [symmetric-simple](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/connection-router/symmetric-simple) examples

Comment: Ok, I could get a working router balancing connections with a `ROUND_ROBIN` policy, without the slave nodes in the `static-connectors`. That's yet another broker instance but that's ok.
My client app has 6 consumers balanced as 4 on masterA and 2 on masterB.
The connection-router element does not seems to be reloaded after a change in `broker.xml`.
Is there a way to avoid having a connection router instance as a SPOF or am I missing something?
ATM, I'm not sure we can easily partition data as you suggest.
We still have to test the connection-router under load.

Comment: To avoid a SPOF you could use a symmetric architecture, see the [symmetric-redirect](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/connection-router/symmetric-redirect) and the [symmetric-simple](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/connection-router/symmetric-simple) examples

Comment: Ah, I see. The HA is handled by both live only nodes, not by a replication policy. That might require more work and tests on our side. There is still something I don’t understand: why are the connections not balanced as 3 on masterA and 3 on masterB with both `ROUND_ROBIN` and `LEAST_CONNECTIONS`? `ROUND_ROBIN` makes a 4-2 whereas `LEAST_CONNECTIONS` puts all the connections on the masterA node. Am I missing something? see the update for the router configuration relevant config elements.